# use of ".*?" in .NET regex

Tags: .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between .*? and .* for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453948/reading-numbers-from-string-in-c), and noticed that many of the regular expressions in the answers used `.*?` to match intermediate text, rather than just `.*`.

To my mind, using `.*` will match any character zero or more times.  Adding `?` would be superfluous, as it would just modify "zero or more" to "zero or more once, or nothing" (in other words, "zero or more, or zero").

Does `.*?` represent a special regex sequence, or is it just an odd way to write `.*` with more characters?

Comment: `?` following repetition specifier is the reluctant/lazy/non-greedy quantifier. See my lengthy answer with examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532

Comment: @polygenelubricants  Thanks!  Unfortunately, searching for ".*?" hadn't turned up anything, despite being in the title for that original question.  Yours is just the answer I was looking for :)